# WordPress adds br in between my shortcode

Tags: shortcode, editor

I am having a problem where my markup is rendered incorrectly (more space because of `<br />`) as WordPress adds `<br />` everywhere theres a line break

eg.

```
[x]
  [y]Hello world[/y]
  [y]A test[/y]
[/x]
```

In the handler for `x` the `$content` looks like

```
<br />
[y]Hello world[/y]
<br />
[y]A test[/y]
<br />
```

Am I suppose to strip out all the line breaks?

**UPDATE**

I notice that no line breaks

```
[x][y]Photoshop[/y][y]Notepad++[/y][/x]
```

`[y]Notepad++[/y]` will not be rendered as a shortcode. I must have a space like

```
[x][y]Photoshop[/y] [y]Notepad++[/y][/x]
                   ^
```

Isit?

Comment: How are you shortcode codes handled? Via a filter on `the_content` or using an actual registered shortcode?

Comment: its registered using `add_shortcode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you register your shortcode, add the filter to the content for unautop:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop' );
```

Do this also for the areas, maybe excerpt or widget, when your shortcode add to this areas.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the post editor, press `CTRL + ENTER` when you go to a new line. Doing that tells WordPress not to add a `<br />` tag in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the above solutions to work, so I did a CSS hack to hide the 
 tags:

```
.my-custom-shortcode br {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any br tags by default ! but if you are getting any in your content without even using them try adding esc_attr  or esc_html before returning the variables that holds the values of your shortcode

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570351/shortcode-output-adding-br-after-new-line).

You have to change the priority of the filter which adds line breaks:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop', 100);
```